# Why when I change the value (file in linux belong to gpio pin) from 1 to 0, nothing changed?

Tags: c++, qt, gpio

I have a [matrix relay](http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/Matrix_-_Relay) with a nanopi fire (like rasperry pi). I connected this relay to my device and want to change gpio value.(my device has multi gpio pin. first I should create gpio(echo 95 > /sys/class/gpio/export) and then change direction folder "out" (echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio95/direction) and with changing value the relay should turn on and off.)
this is my code:

```
bool GPIOClass::ChangeValue(QString IO, QString port)
{
    QString gpio;
    QString comand;
//    comand=" echo ";
//    comand.append(QIO);
//    comand.append(" > ");
//    gpio=config->GpioFromPort(port);

//    if(gpio.length()==0)
//        return false;
//    //IO should be 1 or 0

    QString src=IdenGPIOSrc(gpio);//src is /sys/class/gpio/gpio95
    src.append("/value");

//    comand.append(src);
//    qDebug()<<port<<gpio<<"with src:"
//           <<src <<"with command:"<<comand;
//    system(comand.toStdString().c_str());

    ///===========================================================
    QFile file(src);
    if ( file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly) )
    {
        //clear the content
//        file.resize(0);
        file.seek(0);
        file.write(QByteArray::number(IO.toInt()),1);

    }

    if(GetValue(port)==IO.toInt())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

the relay is not changed, but when I run the executable [sample](http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/Matrix_-_Relay#Code_Sample) the relay is [turn on and off](http://blog.csdn.net/u013606170/article/details/77422207):

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) 
{
    int pin = GPIO_PIN(7); 
    int i, value, board;
    int ret = -1;

    if ((board = boardInit()) < 0) {
        printf("Fail to init board\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (board == BOARD_NANOPI_T2)
        pin = GPIO_PIN(15);

    if (argc == 2)
        pin = GPIO_PIN(atoi(argv[1]));
    if ((ret = exportGPIOPin(pin)) == -1) {   
        printf("exportGPIOPin(%d) failed\n", pin);
    }
    if ((ret = setGPIODirection(pin, GPIO_OUT)) == -1) {
        printf("setGPIODirection(%d) failed\n", pin);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < STATUS_CHANGE_TIMES; i++) {
        if (i % 2) {
            value = GPIO_HIGH;
        } else {
            value = GPIO_LOW;
        }
        if ((ret = setGPIOValue(pin, value)) > 0) {
            printf("%d: GPIO_PIN(%d) value is %d\n", i+1, pin, value);
        } else {
            printf("setGPIOValue(%d) failed\n", pin);
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
    unexportGPIOPin(pin);
    return 0;
}
```

in that code also the value in that address changed like my code (change value file to 1 and 0 ) and the relay is working. where is the diffrence between my code and that code? both of them change the value content.
where is my code problem?

Comment: most obvious difference is that the second piece of code has calls to `exportGPIOPin`,`setGPIODirection` and `setGPIOValue` and the first one does not. Actually I dont see anything that the two snippets have in common, hence your question is rather unclear

Comment: that code create gpio and set gpio direction. I told it (maybe it is unclear in my post that I define it again).My question is I change the value but relay not change.

Comment: what do you define again?

Comment: should create gpio(echo 95 > /sys/class/gpio/export) and then change direction folder "out" (echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio95/direction) and with changing value the relay should turn on and off.) I told it, I do it before changing value of gpio. My problem is just changing value of gpio

Comment: sorry, but I dont get it. Why do you think comparing your code with the example code will help you to find to problem when you are using completely different method of talking to the IOs?

Comment: I just want to know what is the diffrence between my gpio value change and the sample code gpio value change?It uses "high" and "low". they are just change the value content to 1 and 0. I do like it but my matrix rely does not change. I want to know why?

Comment: the difference between your code and the sample code??? I dont see anything that they have in common

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157437/discussion-between-h-ghassami-and-tobi303).